# Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' to 'NSString'

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, uisearchresultscontroller

I am having a very weird problem which I am not able to figure it out of what is going wrong here.

Here is my code

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchWord = searchController.searchBar.text!

    getCountriesNamesFromServer(searchWord)

    let searchPredict = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

     newTableData = [String]()

    for var i = 0; i < self.dict.count - 1; i++ {

        let cityName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
       let countryName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String

            print("countryName is \(countryName)")





    newTableData.append(cityName)
    }
    print("newTableData is \(newTableData)" )
    let array = (newTableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredict)
    print("array is\(array)")
    filterTableData = array as! [String]
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Program is crashing at this line

```
let countryName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
```

when I type first character in the search box all works fine but as soon as I type second character in the `searchBox` program crashes and it gives me this error

**Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x1a03c3768) to 'NSString' (0x1a03cd798).**

and for your Information countryNames exist in the `dict` variable but I don't know why its giving me null value and why city name is successfully working because country also exist in the same array from which I am getting the city

**UPDATE:**

This line prints country name successfully

```
  print("countryName is \(countryName)")
```

Comment: First of all, can you explode the crashing line in multiple lines to knows the exactly line that crashes ?

Comment: sorry what does it mean. I didn't get you ?

Comment: try to print `((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)`. I think the `name` key is not set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, they tell you what the problem is: You've got a result of type NSNull, and NSNull *cannot* be converted to NSString.

Most likely you are processing JSON, and JSON data often contains null values.

Go away from your labyrinth of ? and !

Write some code that helps you. Remember that any ! will crash your application if you don't get what you expect.

When you access the key "name" in a dictionary, you need to handle the case that there is a string (nice for you), nothing (key doesn't exist, very common), null (the server tells you explicitly that there is nothing, very common), a number, bool, dict or array.

For each of these cases, tell me what you want as a result: A crash? An optional string that is nil? An empty string? Typically you want a string if it is there, possibly a number converted to a string if it is a number, and either nil or an empty string if the key isn't there or null, and either a crash or nil if you get a bool, dictionary or array.

Then write a function that returns exactly that. And then you use it. When you write (... as? NSString)! you tell the compiler that you *want* a crash if it's not a string, and that's what you got.

Comment: Thank you very much. line breaks were coming in the country values like this \r .. Now I have removed it from database

Answer (score 1):

@gnasher729 Explained it very well,
but to solve your problem you should use the "?" instead of "!"

so while parsing the data from the code below

```
 let countryName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
```

use the code as

```
let countryName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as? NSString)? as String ?? ""
```

or

```
let countryName = ((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as? String ?? ""
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You received a list of country from your server at this line

```
getCountriesNamesFromServer(searchWord)
```

But I think that its returning you a list without all datas completely set.

```
for var i = 0; i < self.dict.count - 1; i++ {

            let cityName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
            let countryName = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["Country"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String

            print("countryName is \(countryName)")

            newTableData.append(cityName)
        }
```

On the first iteration of your loop the `name` value is set correctly so it works but at the second iteration, it is, in my opinion, `null` and you cannot cast `NSNull` to `NSString` so the application crashes.

Before casting to `NSString`, if you are not sure of the server response, you must try if the dictionary contains the `name` key and if the value is set. If it is, you can try to cast it.

If you want, you can also use an external library `SwiftyJSON` to simplify the parsing of `JSON` response.